# Nextjs auth with Firebase not sharing cookie accross pages

Tags: javascript, cookies, firebase-authentication, next.js

I'm trying to create auth using Firebase and NextJS
I followed this tutorial: [https://colinhacks.com/essays/nextjs-firebase-authentication][1].

Whenever I access an SSR authenticated page the token is deleted from the front end, firebase gives an error stating  `FirebaseAuthError: First argument to verifyIdToken() must be a Firebase ID token string..`

It seems like the cookie is deleted whenever SSR is run because Firebase see's the cookie as invalid. I've tried setting the cookie using js-cookie and using nookies.

I've tried different cookie frameworks for setting cookies, the NextJS native method of fetching cookies SSR and nookies for fetching cookies SSR.

auth.js

```
const AuthContext = createContext<{ user: firebaseClient.User | null }>({
    user: null,
});
export function AuthProvider({ children }: any) {
    const [user, setUser] = useState<firebaseClient.User | null>(null);
    console.log("User is ", user)
    useEffect(() => {
        if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
            (window as any).nookies = nookies;
        }
        return firebaseClient.auth().onIdTokenChanged(async (user) => {
            if (!user) {
                setUser(null);
                // Cookies.set("token", "");
                nookies.set(null, "token", "",);
                return;
            }

            const token = await user.getIdToken();
            // Cookies.set("token", token);
            nookies.set(null, "token", token, {
                path: "/",
                encode: (v) => v,
            });
            setUser(user);

        });
    }, []);
    useEffect(() => {
        const handle = setInterval(async () => {
            console.log(`refreshing token...`);
            const user = firebaseClient.auth().currentUser;
            if (user) await user.getIdToken(true);
        }, 10 * 60 * 1000);
        return () => clearInterval(handle);
    }, []);

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{ user }}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>
    );
}

export const useAuth = () => {
    return useContext(AuthContext);
};
```

Authenticated page

```
export const getServerSideProps = async (ctx, req) => {
  try {
  const cookies = nookies.get(ctx);
   // Fails here, never accepts token
    const token = await firebaseAdmin.auth().verifyIdToken(cookies.token);
    console.log("Token is:", token)
    return {
      props: {
        data: "Worked!"
      },
    };
  } catch (err) {
    return {
      props: {
        data: "Firebase failed!"
      },
    };
  }
};

const Revisions = ({ data, ctx }) => {
  const { user } = useAuth();
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Container>
        {/* always returns no user signed in */}
        <p>{`User ID: ${user ? user.uid : 'no user signed in'}`}</p>
        <p>{data}</p>
      </Container>
    </Layout>
  );
};
```

EDIT: Additional information
On the loginpage cookie is set on the front end. I can see this cookie in my Applications tab.
[![Application tab chrome showing token and value][2]][2]

I have verified that localhost with the correct port is permitted through the firebase console.

The token seems to get deleted at this line

```
const token = await firebaseAdmin.auth().verifyIdToken(cookie);
```

I have tried using JSON parse, both with JSON.stringify first and just straight JSON parsing the data.
[1]: https://colinhacks.com/essays/nextjs-firebase-authentication
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8MES.png

Comment: Can you see the expected cookie set in the browser?

Comment: Yes, it is set as it should it seems. Path is root and I see all the data. But when I run it through a server rendered page with firebase auth the token is unset. It seems like in passing the token to server render it is somehow malformated.

Comment: @Andreas did you ever get this to work. I'm having a similar issue ?

Comment: I got this to work using the API-method in NextJS instead of getServerSideProps (so sending the cookie to a file in the /api-folder, getting data there and returning it). But then I got annoyed at the lack of docs and re-wrote everything to use the auth library from Auth0 for Nextjs